# Tiny MCE editor center tag issue

Tags: html, editor

I am facing an issue using tiny MCE editor as below:

I have HTML data with  center  tag but when I tried to align the content to left using Tiny MCE editor  alignment options its not working its still showing me center   tag in source code.
Can any body help me on this if I have content with html center  tag then tiny MCE editor alignments options can work.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks
Vik

Comment: Show us Html data and point us where is the problem,so we can help you.

Comment: You can use below link to test the case. https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/basic-example/           and case is add center tag like < center > hi I am center tag < / center > in tiny MCE source code. And view the content in normal mode and try to use alignment options on it. It will not work.

Comment: This is centered: <center> hi I am center tag </ center > in Firefox. If you clicked left option it will be left with html code: <p style="padding-left: 60px; text-align: center;">hi I am center tag</p>. What is the issue :)

Comment: If the text is around with center tag then tiny MCE editor left and right alignments does not work. You can check in chrome or in internet  explorer.

Comment: It may be compatibility issue. Can you try using Firefox and test if your issue exist.

Comment: Issue still the same just try in chrome and in IE with HTML as <center>This is center Tag</center> in source code of tiny mce editor.